# How to copy table fast from one database to another

Tags: android, sqlite, fts3

I have one database with one table and another database. I need to copy this one table from the first database (with simple table) to the second. (In second database it should be fts3 table). So, I can open both databases, create new fts3 in the second db and copy all data from the first to the second via select -> insert queries. But is there any other ways to do it faster and better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know the methodology you described (i.e. `INSERT INTO db2.tbl SELECT * FROM db1.tbl`) should generally be the most efficient.

What you can do is tweak sqlite to do it faster. The first thing that comes to mind is to disable [journaling](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_journal_mode) (normally dangerous, but should be acceptable in your scenario as you still have an original of the data):

```
pragma PRAGMA journal_mode=OFF:
```

You can also turn off the [`synchronous` pragma](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_synchronous) (also dangerous):

```
PRAGMA synchronous=OFF;
```

There are one or two more pragmas you can play with that could make a difference, but I think the two I mention will have the biggest impact.

Be sure to restore those pragmas to their original values after the copy.

Answer (score 3):

Well yes, that is the best way. Create table and then insert the data:

```
INSERT INTO `toDB`.`tableName` SELECT * FROM `fromDB`.`tableName`
```

Comment: HI @bArmageddon  I have one sqlite database in my sdcard and i want to copy table into my application database in android Is it Posible??