# How to Download file in /databases folder with Downloadmanager class?

Tags: android

Well there are good explanation about Download manager [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog)

And also there is a good tutorial about DM [here](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Internet/Download)

But both of them didnt tell how to download into different directory. how can download my database file into the databases folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to download your db **somewhere else** (i.e.: a `/temp` directory in your sd card).
An example on how to do this can be found here: http://www.androidsnippets.com/download-an-http-file-to-sdcard-with-progress-notification

Then copy data from the db in that **temporary** directory to your actual db and finally delete the downloaded db.
An example on how to do that is found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10371472/2649012

This one isn't a complete example, youst a "kick" into the right direction.

Comment: I edited my answer to show you a couple of key example codes. The second isn't a complete example, youst a "kick" into the right direction.

Comment: How can I found my download file in `Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS`

Answer (score 1):

try this to download your file:

```
    try {
        URL url = new URL(" <URL HERE> ");
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.connect();

        String DatbasesPath = Environment.getDataDirectory() + "/data/" + getApplication().getPackageName() + "/databases/";
        File file = new File(DatbasesPath, "mydb.db");
        FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);
        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bufferLength = 0;
        while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
            fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
        }
        fileOutput.close();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `DownloadManager.Request` object use [setDestinationInExternalPublicDir](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request.html#setDestinationInExternalPublicDir%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method to change destination and name.

Or [`setDestinationUri`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request.html#setDestinationUri%28android.net.Uri%29) which does only what you want.

Documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request.html#setDestinationInExternalPublicDir%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).